# vb.net server Socket dismiss previous client after new accepting new client

Tags: vb.net, sockets

> as i told in title , server doesnt listen previous client's packets. I
>   just need server to read all packets coming from multiple clients.
>
> here s my code , thanks for your help
>
> ```
>     serverSocket = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
>     Dim ipAddress As IPAddress = ipAddress.Parse("192.168.2.202")
>     Dim IpEndPoint As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 15002)
>     serverSocket.Bind(IpEndPoint)
>     serverSocket.Listen(1500)
>     serverSocket.BeginAccept(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnAccept), Nothing)
> ```
>
> Delegate Sub _OnAccept(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
>       Private Sub OnAccept(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
>
> ```
>     If InvokeRequired Then
>         Invoke(New _OnAccept(AddressOf OnAccept), ar)
>
>         Exit Sub
>     End If
>
>     clientSocket = serverSocket.EndAccept(ar)
>     serverSocket.BeginAccept(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnAccept), Nothing)
>
>
>     Try
>         clientSocket.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnRecieve),
> ```
>
> clientSocket)
>           Catch ex As Exception
>
> ```
>     End Try
>
>
>     AddClient(clientSocket)
> End Sub
> Delegate Sub _AddClient(ByVal client As Socket) 'delege used to invoke AddCLient()
> Private Sub AddClient(ByVal client As Socket)
>
>     If InvokeRequired Then
>         Invoke(New _AddClient(AddressOf AddClient), client)
>
>         Exit Sub
>     End If
>     Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(client.LocalEndPoint.ToString)
>     lvi.Tag = client
>     ListBox1.Items.Add(client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString & " Bağlandı")
>
> End Sub
> ```
>
> Delegate Sub _OnRecieve(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
>       Private Sub OnRecieve(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
>           If InvokeRequired Then
>               Invoke(New _OnRecieve(AddressOf OnRecieve), ar)
>               Exit Sub
>           End If
>
> ```
>     Dim client As Socket = ar.AsyncState
>     Try
>         client.EndReceive(ar)
>     Catch ex As Exception
>
>     End Try
>
>     Dim bytesRec As Byte() = byteData
>     Dim paket As String = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesRec)
>
>     Dim temizip As String
>     temizip = Replace(paket, Chr(0), Chr(32))
>     temizip = temizip.Trim
>
>     Dim msg As String = temizip
>
>     Try
>
>         Dim boyut As Integer
>         boyut = msg(0) & msg(1)
>         boyut = boyut - 10
>
>         Dim externalip As String
>         externalip = msg.Remove(0, 2)
>         externalip = externalip.Remove(boyut, (externalip.Length - boyut))
>
>        If clientlist.Contains(externalip) Then
>         Else
>             clientlist.Add(externalip)
>
>         End If
>
>
>
>
>
>     Catch ex As Exception
>
>     End Try
>
>
>     Try
>         clientSocket.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnRecieve),
> ```
>
> clientSocket)
>           Catch ex As Exception
>
> ```
>     End Try
>
> End Sub
> ```

thanks people i solved this , i declare new clientsocket for each client and its solved. 
i just delete clientSocket variable from the header code , and i re-declared it on every thread.

Comment: Small point here, but `boyut = msg(0) & msg(1)` for an integer type? Put `Option Strict On` to fix these small errors. Have you debugged your `OnReceive` event?

Comment: all of tehm works good , theres a little error on this , when a new client connects server stopped to listen on previous client . I need to BeginReceive all clients at the same time. Its dismissing previous client and  starting to listen new one.

Comment: For help formatting your question, click the orange question mark in the editor.  Also, please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (sockets, multiple, clients) will not help categorize it.  **Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!**